# php comma separated string to... object?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a piece of php code that is submitting data to a database. Prior to that I do validation on other fields. If there are missing fields, I throw an error and echo the post data back to those fields.

I am using a jQuery plugin as well and need to send that data back the the plugin to re-invoke the tags.

```
 $("#tags").select2({
    tags: <?php if(isset($_POST['action'])) { 
                    if ($_GET['action'] != 'success'){ 
                        echo $_POST['tags']; }
                    }else{ 
                        echo '[]'; 
                    } ?>,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
});
```

It needs to be in this format:

`["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]`

How can I achieve this from a comma separated string? `tag1,tag2,tag3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `json_encode` function:

```
echo json_encode( explode(',', $_POST['tags']) );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 5.2 or later, you can use `json_encode` to convert your object/array to json.

```
$tags = explode(',',$_POST['tags']);
echo json_encode($tags);
```

convert object/array to json
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Split string to an array by delimiter
http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.explode.php